# Why javascript "write() function" isn't working when referring to an element by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys,
My array is printing it's values on page when:

```
document.write(unsorted[i]+"<br/>");
```

but not when trying to put it in a div referring the element by jquery

```
$("#no1").write(unsorted[i]+"<br/>");
```

Here's my code:

```
$(function(){ 
    var unsorted = new Array();
    function randomNumber(x,y) { //gives a random number
      return Math.floor((Math.abs(y - x) + 1) * Math.random()) + Math.min(x, y);
    }

    for(i=0; i<=33; i++){
        unsorted[i]=randomNumber(0,33);     //populates the array with random numbers
        $("#no1").write(unsorted[i]+"<br/>");   //#no1 is a div
    }
});
```

Jquery library is tested and works fine whatever is it's my code!
Any suggestions why my approach is wrong appreciate any help
10x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use the `document.write` method when the page is loading, you can't write to elements that already exist.

Put the content together, and use the `html` method in the jQuery library to put the content in the div:

```
var s = [];
for(i = 0; i <= 33; i++){
  unsorted[i] = randomNumber(0, 33);
  s.push(unsorted[i]);
}
$("#no1").html(s.join("<br/>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method:

```
$("#no1").html($("#no1").html() + unsorted[i]+"<br/>");
```

> Set the HTML contents of each element
>   in the set of matched elements.

Comment: It's much nicer to use the callback signature: `$('#no1').html(function(idx, oldHtml){return oldHtml + unsorted[i] + '<br/>';});` provided you have jQuery 1.4.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Rightly said unless jquery 1.4 is there. Your comment is useful here though :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the jQuery function `$('selector')` doesn't return the document object, it returns a jQuery object, so appending `.write` to it isn't going to work because the jQuery object doesn't include a `write` method. It's not the same as saying `document.write`.

Secondly, you wouldn't use `document.write` for this anyway; `document.write` can only be called before the page has loaded, so it can't be used with JQuery (which can only be used after the page has loaded, due to the loading order of files in the browser).

JQuery does provide various functions that you can use instead. Others have already suggested using `.html()`, to change the contents of your `<div>`.

This is a good suggestion. But frankly you don't even need jQuery for this. Since you're directly referencing a element with an ID, you could simply use standard the Javascript and DOM methods `getElementById()` and innerHTML

```
document.getElementById('no1').innerHTML += unsorted[i]+"<br/>";
```

The jquery alternative would only be necessary in this case if you were wanting to do a more complex selector (eg selecting by class or more than one element at a time, etc), but for a simple ID-based selection, standard Javascript does the job just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.write()` try

```
$("#no1").html($("#no1").html() + unsorted[i]+"<br/>");
```

Comment: Don't append by reading and writing `html()`. This forces the browser to serialise, destroy and re-parse DOM content, which is slow and loses non-serialisable content such as event handlers. Use `append()` instead.